# Displaying Username after login in angular application

Tags: javascript, angular

I am storing the Username after logged in. Getting the name using method  by returning.
When I logged off and log in with another user. old user name is displaying. How I can resolve this?

Comment: Show some code to let us know what you are doing?

Comment: From where are you getting the name is it from service or some storage

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove old user when you log off using that user.

Comment: I am removing using Session.remove();